# Buy Now button on category page (listing page)

Tags: magento-1.9, magento1.9.2.3

I want to show "Buy Now" button on listing page i.e. on category page, after click on buy now it will redirect to onepage checkout. I used "

```
<button onclick="location.href ='<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product);?>′">Buy It Now</button>
```

" 
It will redirect to cart page but i need to redirect on onepagecheckout.

Comment: try this helper('checkout/onepage')

Comment: no, its didn't work from listing page. I need to redirect on onestepcheck.

Comment: i tried with this also
$checkout_link = Mage::helper('checkout/url')->getCheckoutUrl();
<button onclick="location.href ='<?php echo $checkout_link;?>'">Buy It Now</button>
it will redirect, but product is not added in cart :(

Comment: update your checkout page url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code:

Buy now button code as below:

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Buy Now') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="addProductCheckout('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>','<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/url') ?>')">
    <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Buy Now') ?></span></span></button>
```

Ajax code as below:

```
<script>
  function addProductCheckout(addtocart,checkouturl)
     {
        jQuery.ajax({
                      url:addtocart,
                      success:function(data){
                          window.location.href = checkouturl;
                      }
                   });
      }
</script>
```

Comment: If it helps you, mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Just send anthor parameter(`return_url=$this->getUrl("checkout/onepage")`) with **add to cart** url

**Change to**

```
<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product).'?return_url=$this->getUrl("checkout/onepage")';?>">
```

**from**

```
<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product);?>
```